# 1/0 Knapsack, how to make it parallel with priority queue

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing, priority-queue, mathematical-optimization

In 1/0 Knapsack Problem, one can implement it dynamically with two for loops, like
on this site: http://www.bogotobogo.com/Algorithms/knapsack.php

How can i implement it with a priority queue and optimize it with multithreading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the algorithm in the section "0-1 Knapsack - Dynamic Programming", the inner loop can be parallelized. The execution of the loop's body for different values of `jw` can be executed in parallel as the calculation of the value for `m[i][jw]` does not require values `m[i][jw']` where `jw'!=jw`, i.e. any iteration does not depend on previous iterations.